# Symfony 5: controller requires that you provide a value for an argument

Tags: php, symfony, controller, locale, breadcrumbs

I have recently bought a new computer. Both old and new have ***xampp over Windows 10***. After I have **copied** all my **apache**, **mysql** and **php** configuration files to the new one and once checked everything can run. I find an **error** on one of my symfony sites homepage **using exactly the same files I was using previously**.

> Controller "App\Controller\FrontendController::index()" requires that
> you provide a value for the "$locale" argument. Either the argument is
> nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has
> been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this
> one.

In order to check for the possible error I have created a new FrontendController class with the minimal code I needed in order to reproduce my error.

Here is the code that does not generate the error:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class FrontendController extends AbstractController 
{

    /** 
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     */

    public function index(
      Request $request,
      string $locale = 'es'
    ) {
      dd($locale);
    }
  }
```

Here is the code that DOES generate the error. The only difference is that I add WhiteOctober/BreadcrumbsBundle that works like a charm in my installation on the previous computer.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use WhiteOctober\BreadcrumbsBundle\Model\Breadcrumbs;

class FrontendController extends AbstractController 
{

    /** 
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     */

    public function index(
      Request $request,
      string $locale = 'es',
      Breadcrumbs $breadcrumbs
    ) {
      dd($locale);
    }
  }
```

Again, when I remove $locale from the parameters list, things also work:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use WhiteOctober\BreadcrumbsBundle\Model\Breadcrumbs;

class FrontendController extends AbstractController 
{

    /** 
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     */

    public function index(
      Request $request,
      Breadcrumbs $breadcrumbs
    ) {
      dd("Without locale");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not sure why this worked on your last install. Have you tried putting `$local` after breadcrumbs? Set the default within the route annotation also..

Comment: It's possible you need to [set a default locale](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html#setting-a-default-locale).  The link also provides additional info on how Symfony handles locale.

Comment: @Cerad thanks for your comment but my translations.yaml file is already set: `framework:
    default_locale: es
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - en
            - fr`

Comment: `because there is a non optional argument after this one.` Like Bossman indicated, this could be the problem.  I suspect there might be more going on than is posted.  Does `$request->getLocale()` return the expected value?  And there should be no need to use $locale = 'es' since Symfony always provides a default value.  `string $locale` really should do the trick.  Good luck with Windows 10.

Comment: Hi @Bossman I did so and yes, the error does not show. Now what is the reason the order of arguments make this error happen? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It is how the router is reading the annotation then the method, setting a default for the parameter will solve it otherwise the order matters. As Cerad says `because there is a non optional argument after this one.` shows.

Comment: Ok, I got it, just say that in my previous computer and in the online server where I show the results to my client none of these errors showed. And I use the same version of symfony in all of them. That mistery remains unresolved but yet I must move forward. Thank you so much for your help.